# How to retrieve 1 picture URL from each unique Firestore document and set the img.src with that picURL?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I want to go into every document in a specific collection and retrieve a saved picURL, and then set the src to an img tag in an li. I have tried a code, and it works partly. It sets the img src, but it is the same src. I want to retrieve two (or more) different picURLs and set these as the img src to two (or more) unique img srcs. I hope this question makes sense, it is pretty hard to explain. I will add some pictures and the code snippet to help understand.

Javascript:

```
var postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts')

postDocRef.get().then(snapshot => {
setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})

const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

const setupPosts = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        let li = `
        <li class="post">
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
        `;

        var imgRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts');
        imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {
            
            if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                
                let doc = snapshot.docs[0]
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const picURL = data.picURL

                    li += `<img class="img" src="${picURL}">`;         
            }

            li += "</li><br></br>";
            html += li
            posts.innerHTML = html;
        })
    })
}
});
```

[Here is the structure of my database (collection userPosts, where I want to go into each document) (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGnhW.png)

[This is how one document is structured. I want to retrieve the picURL in every document. (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpbZD.png)

Comment: the solution does not work? if not, share more details, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
var postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts')

postDocRef.get().then(snapshot => {
setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})

const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

const setupPosts = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        let li = `<li class="post">
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>`;
        
        li += (post.picURL ? `<img class="img" src="${post.picURL}">` : ``);
        li += `</li><br></br>`;
        html += li
    })
    
    posts.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but I want to check if the picURL exists in the document before adding it to the img tag in the li. If it doesn't exist I want to just add the title and the content. The code I tried did this but added the same image to every post.